# Object construction differences

Tags: javascript, object-oriented

Whenever I create a Javascript "class" I do something like this:

```
// Definition
function MyObject() {
   this.id = 0;
   this.legs = 2;
}
MyObject.prototype = {
   walk: function() {
      // Do stepping
   },
   stop: function() {
      // Stop stepping
   }
};

// Instanciation
var TestMyObject = new MyObject();
TestMyObject.id = 1;
TestMyObject.legs = 3;
```

However, as I was trying to find a way to do fixed time step timers, I found another way to construct objects by passing in a key value pair object.  That got me thinking that it could be convenient to construct MY objects in a similar fashion.  So is there a problem with creating an object like this:

```
// Definition
function MyObject(objectSettings) {
   // Essentially acts as default constructor
   objectSettings = objectSettings || {};

   // Without a given parameter, use default
   this.id = objectSettings.id || 0;
   this.legs = objectSettings.legs || 2;

   // Make sure the reference is gone
   objectSettings = null; // Do I even need this?
}
MyObject.prototype = {
   walk: function() {
   },
   stop: function() {
   }
};

// Instanciation

// Use all defaults
var TestMyObject01 = new MyObject();

// Set only id
var TestMyObject02 = new MyObject({
   id: 1
});

// Set everything
var TestMyObject02 = new MyObject({
   id: 1,
   legs: 3
});
```

My question is, `objectSettings` doesn't stick around after instantiating the new object right?  Maybe I'm being paranoid.  I'm still trying to wrap my head around closures and initially I had a `var` inside the definition that referenced the passed `objectSettings` but I figured that was a bad choice because that would be a private immutable reference to a hunk of memory that was just used to copy into an object and that memory wouldn't go away as long as the created object was around.

I realize it would probably be even easier to pass values in individually to the constructor, but I thought maybe this would be a way to overcome the limitation of not being able to overload a function based on parameter type.  I would pass what I want to set specifically and if it isn't in the passed object (or if there is no passed object at all) the parameter would be set to a default value.  Is there a better way to construct objects in a similar fashion?

I can't find the link to the timer object that got me on this but If I do find it, I'll link it here.

Comment: Welcome! Yes, it certainly looks like you have come to the right place!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct, the lifetime of `objectSettings` is only for the `MyObject` function, so you don't need the assignment to `null` at the end.

Passing in an object to the constructor is a common pattern to set its properties, and if you don't want to add specific assignment statements for each property, you can do something like this:

```
Utils = {
  // Taken from the ExtJS library
  apply: function(o, c, defaults) {
    if(defaults) {
      Utils.apply(o, defaults);
    }
    if(o && c && typeof c == 'object') {
      for(var p in c) {
        o[p] = c[p];
      }
    }
    return o;
  }
};

function MyObject(cfg) {
  Utils.apply(this, cfg, {
    id: 0,
    legs: 2,
    ...
  });

  // You now have access to this.id, etc.
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks.  It occurred to me while I was testing that you define a ton of objects in JQuery using this method so I should have taken that as a cue that this was safe.  Still though, good to be assured that I'm not leaking memory.